# ASP.NET Web API authorization and Authentication

Tags: rest, authentication, authorization, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to build a secure asp.net web api. You can find a lot of ways of how to secure your API, but I want to know what is the best way or the 'industry standard' to implement this for my case.

These are my requirements
- The API will be used by a small number of third-party developers for websites/mobile apps etc.
- Developers who want to use this API have to be given a key to access the API (Authorization)
- Users (Visitors/consumers) have to login into the third-party apps to see their personalized information.
- The API will use an ASP membership database for managing/authenticating the users.

I know it's possible to use http basic authentication for authenticating users, but how do I implement the authorization part of the API?

Is OAuth 2.0 a solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a very good article describing the authentication/authorization with token/key:

- [Making your ASP.NET Web API’s secure](http://codebetter.com/johnvpetersen/2012/04/02/making-your-asp-net-web-apis-secure/)

It also describes some other good practices regarding ASP.NET Web API security.

Answer (score 6):

I would also suggest the use of the [Thinktecture.IndentityModel.40](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.40) library that can support the following:

**Base**

- Base64Url encoding
- Epoch Date Time conversion
- Random number generation
- Time-constant string comparison

**Claims**

- Anoynmous claims principal
- Authentication instant claim
- Claims-based authorization

**Constant**

- Useful constants when dealing with algorithms, date time formats, JWT, SWT, WS-Security & WS-Trust

**Extension Methods**

- XML (to and from XmlReader, XmlDocument, XDocument)
- WS-Trust RSTRs
- Security token conversion
- X.509 Certificates